# What happen with my app when I close SQL server?

Tags: java, sql-server

I’m coursing my first database lessons, recently I made a little java app to connect  sql server via jdbc just to check if the app was saving the data, what happen if I close sql server and still run the app?

Comment: *close sql server* - what do you mean?

Comment: When I was checking if the the data was inserted in the tables I was checking that information in the sql server management studio and when i saw that the data  was inserted correctly the question came to my mind, if I close the sql management studio I think the connection as well, so if I run my app that is supposed to save the in a DB, it will insert the data or not?

Comment: *it will insert the data or not?* - why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 0):

If by *close sql server* you mean stop the service your app will fail when trying to interact with sql server, if you handle the exceptions that this will cause what will happen is what you decide.

If what you mean was close the sql server management tool nothing will happen, your app will continue working as expected.